# Setting fixed extent in ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-online-basemaps, story-map

I'm creating an Esri Story Map and trying to set a fixed extent for my maps.  For example, if I'm trying to illustrate fire stations in the City of Denver, CO I don't want my users to be able to zoom/pan half way across the globe on accident.

I understand that I can set an initial extent - http://www.esri.com/esri-news/arcuser/fall-2013/control-the-map-extent-in-arcgis-online but this doesn't prevent the user from zooming/panning away from my data.  I tried to customize my URL according to this source https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/reference/use-url-parameters.htm but haven't been successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ArcGIS Idea entitled [Limit/Lock Map Extent in ArcGIS Online](https://geonet.esri.com/ideas/7015) has now been set to Implemented:

> Starting with the September 2016 release the Minimalist configurable
>   app template now has the option to "Disable all map navigation". This
>   locks the map in its current extent which prevents panning and
>   zooming.

Comment: But what if you want to allow the user to zoom in or out to certain extents BUT NOT pan out of bounds?

Comment: @TheoF That sounds like a new question which could start by mentioning and providing a link to this Q&A.

Comment: I think it's part of the OP's question, as they say: 'I don't want my users to be able to zoom/pan half way across the globe on accident'. So a fix for panning out of extent is requested.

Comment: @TheoF while your interpretation of their question is not unreasonable, they explicitly mention setting a fixed rather than maximum extent so I think you’re looking for an answer to a different question.

Answer (score 1):

Currently not possible but is under consideration as an ArcGIS Idea entitled [Limit/Lock Map Extent in ArcGIS Online](https://geonet.esri.com/ideas/7015).

You can kind of do it by turning off the zoom controls and scroll zoom.